# Error importing PopupModule.forRoot()

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, popup

I have a working angular 2 project. I need to make a popup form to fill in details in a table. Upon clicking a button I want to have a popup form wherein user can enter details and submit. For this I have been trying to use `ng2-opd-popup` component of Angular 2. But its throwing me following error when I added `PopupModule.forRoot()` in `imports` of `@NgModule` in my `app.module.ts` file. I have installed it using `npm install ng2-opd-popup`.

> vendor.9f5a936….js:253
>    Uncaught SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule' at SyntaxError.Base…}

Any help would be appreciated. By the way I am following [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup) for popup component and I am using webpack.

Part of app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import { PopupModule } from 'ng2-opd-popup';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AgGridModule.forRoot(),
        PopupModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
```

Comment: Can you show app.module.ts file?

Comment: @Amit Chigadani, I have included part of app.module.ts file. Can you tell me what exactly you are looking for in `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: @phanny Did you solve this issue? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Hello , I got  the same error today on trying to create a new project and specially during imports part, when I add in imports sections in app.module the "PopupModule.forRoot() .  Did someone find out a solution ?

Comment: Duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568748/after-adding-ng2-opd-popup-module-in-app-module-ts-page-getting-some-error-in-an

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to go inside your ng2-opd-popup folder and delete the node_modules folder inside there. it is not needed. after it, everything is worked ok.